# Quiero escribir en un archivo sin remplazar el texto un "dict" sin las " " de los string

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

```
mind = {"message": "null", "mID": "0", "reply": "null"}    

mind["mID"] = random.randint(0,1000000000000)
mind["message"] = getMessage
mind["reply"] = strReply
```

Asumiendo un funcionamiento solo hipotetico, querria lograr que al llamar a la funcion ( digamosle write ) `mindTEXT = temp.write(mind)` escriba en `TEMP.json`

```
{"mensaje": "hola", "miID": "123", "reply": "hola"}
```

( El contenido del dict puede ser ignorado, solo quiero que se sepa que al momento de escribirlo se cambia )

Quiero lograrlo "limpio" por decirlo de algun modo. Pero al llamar la funcion `write` (transformando `mind` en un `String` anteriormente) como es logico devuelve el mensaje en forma de string : `"{"mensaje": "hola", "miID": "123", "reply": "hola"}"`

Lo que quiero lograr es quitar esos " " para poderlo usar como un dict dese python usando la libreria `JSON`.

Se me olvido mencionar la funcionalidad, quizas sea de ayuda:

El objetivo es que al yo escribir en X input esos datos se almacenan en un JSON pero no sobreescriben el actual archivo ( de modo que dump no me sirve ).
Mi objetivo seria algo asi:

```
z = input("Escribe :")
```

Ahora paso z por una funcion la cual pasaria a lograr 2 datos:

- getMessage ( El mensaje que he escrito )
- strReply ( Aun no tiene funcionalidad, pero devuelve "null")

Con estos datos quiero escribirlos en un JSON de este modo ( del dict al JSON):

```
MIND.json
---------

{"mensaje": "hola", "miID": "123", "reply": "hola"}
```

De este modo podria usarlo desde python como si fuese un dict.

Comment: El dict es un dict creado en python. Y perdona las molestias, he editado la pregunta un poco tarde, querria no sobreeescribir el archivo. Si uso dump no se borra lo que ya tiene el archivo?

Comment: Si usas dump se sobreescribe, sí. Pero si no usas dump sino que pretendes _añadir_ entonces el resultado no será JSON válido, ya que un objeto JSON debe contener un solo objeto, o una lista de objetos (separados por comas y encerrada entre corchetes toda la lista), y no una serie de objetos JSON, uno por línea.

Comment: Es decir que no es posible hacer en JSON ( al menos con mis limitados conocimientos actuales en el tema ) una especie de base de datos pasando diccionarios a un mismo JSON ? (Perdon si me explico mal, no es mi punto fuerte)

Comment: Creo que te he entendido. Mi respuesta te da dos posibles formas de hacerlo. Una que asegura que el fichero es JSON correcto, pero el método no es muy eficiente, y otra más eficiente que produce JSON no estándar, pero que puede leerse de todas formas si se hace línea por línea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no entendí mal, creo que lo que quieres hacer es añadir a un fichero ya existente una nueva línea con otro objeto JSON.

Es decir, supongo que tienes algo como esto:

```
datos = funcion_que_genera_diccionario_python()
# Ahora datos es un diccionario python que contiene por ejemplo
# {"mensaje": "hola", "miID": "123", "reply": "hola"}

# Abrimos fichero en modo "a" para añadir
with open("fichero.json", "a") as f:
   # Convertimos en cadena el diccionario python
   cadena = json.dumps(datos)
   # Y la añadimos al fichero
   f.write(cadena)
   # Retorno de carro
   f.write("\n")
```

Si ejecutas eso varias veces, el  `fichero.json` tendría algo así:

```
{"mensaje": "hola", "miID": "123", "reply": "hola"}
{"mensaje": "hola", "miID": "123", "reply": "hola"}
{"mensaje": "hola", "miID": "123", "reply": "hola"}
```

Si ese es tu objetivo, el ejemplo anterior debería hacer lo que esperas. Como verás en el archivo json no se guardan las comillas alrededor de cada línea como mencionabas en la pregunta.

**Sin embargo** debo advertirte que ese fichero no es JSON válido, pues contiene varios objetos y un JSON válido ha de contener solo uno (aunque ese uno podría ser una lista en la que hubiera más).

Es decir, que si intentas leer el fichero anterior como si fuera un JSON así:

```
with open("fichero.json") as f:
    datos = json.load(f)
```

obtendrás el error

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 53)
```

porque una vez ha leido el primer objeto ya no espera más, pero encuentra más.

Si quieres que sea posible volver a leer como JSON lo que has volcado, lo que tienes que hacer es que ese fichero guarde una lista en vez de una serie de diccionarios. Algo así:

```
datos = funcion_que_genera_diccionario_python()

# Leemos del fichero JSON todos los diccionarios que teníamos
# guardados de ejecuciones anteriores, que serán una lista
with open("fichero.json") as f:
   anteriores = json.loads(f)

# Añadimos el nuevo diccionario a la lista anterior
anteriores.append(datos)

# Volvemos a abrir el fichero y volcamos la nueva lista
with open("fichero.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(anteriores, f)
```

Para que funcione correctamente, el `fichero.json` debería existir antes de ejecutar por primera vez el programa, y contener una lista vacía, así:

```
[]
```

Tras varias ejecuciones el fichero contendría algo así (lo formateo para que se vea mejor, pero probablemente sería todo pegado en una sola línea):

```
[
{"mensaje": "hola", "miID": "123", "reply": "hola"},
{"mensaje": "hola", "miID": "123", "reply": "hola"},
{"mensaje": "hola", "miID": "123", "reply": "hola"}
]
```

Esto sí es JSON válido, pues se trata de un solo objeto: una lista que tiene dentro varios diccionarios.

### Nota sobre eficiencia

El enfoque anterior garantiza que el `fichero.json` siempre tiene JSON válido, pero a costa de que cada vez que se ejecuta el programa se tarda más en generar ese fichero (pues debe leer y procesar lo que tenía antes, añadirle otro diccionario y volver a volcarlo todo).

El primer enfoque que simplemente añadía lineas al fichero al abrirlo en modo "a" era mucho más eficiente, pero tenía el inconveniente de que lo que generaba no era JSON válido, por lo que no podías leerlo con `json.load()`.

Una posible solución intermedia es usar el modo "append" como en la primera parte de la respuesta, pero cuando luego vayas a leer el fichero no intentar hacerlo en un solo `json.load()`, que fallará, sino procesarlo línea a línea y cada línea (que sería una cadena con un JSON válido) parsearla con `json.loads()`.

Así por ejemplo:

```
todos_los_json = []
with open("fichero.json") as f:
   for linea in f:
       todos_los_json.append(json.loads(lineea))
```

Al terminar el bucle tendrás una lista en la que cada elemento es un diccionario python.